# Using PendingIntent() to request location updates when running on an O device

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

Using PendingIntent.getService(...) has been the common way to request location updates. Can this still be used for apps running on O devices to receive background location updates?

Answer (score 0):

Apps targeting N or lower (and running on an O or lower device) may use either `PendingIntent.getService()` or `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` when calling [FusedLocationPRoviderApi#requestLocationUpdates](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, android.app.PendingIntent)).

Apps targeting O should only use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`  (and define a `BroadcastReceiver` and register it in the manifest) in order to continue to receive location updates while in the background.  This is because apps targeting O are [subject to limits on services started in the background](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html).

Apps targeting O can continue to use `PendingIntent.getService()` if it only needs to receive location updates while in the foreground.

Comment: Why do you say that App targeting Android O should only use PendingIntent.getBroadcast()? Documentation says to use PendingIntent.getService() 

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, android.app.PendingIntent)